# Integrate by part for vector analysis

Tags: vector-analysis

I am trying to solve problem 1.15 in Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics (3rd Edition). I found a bunch of solutions (proofs) to the problem, one of which shows:
$$
\begin{align*}
 \delta W &=\epsilon_0\int_V \nabla \Phi\cdot\nabla\delta\Phi \ d^3x\\=&\epsilon_0\nabla\Phi\delta\Phi\bigg|_{\partial V}-\epsilon_0\int_V \delta\Phi\nabla\Phi\ d^3x
\end{align*}
$$
where, $\delta\Phi$ is a small incremental of potential $\Phi$.
The last step was derived by integration by parts. This most puzzled me. To me, the correct integration by parts would be
$$
\epsilon_0\int_V \nabla \Phi\cdot\nabla\delta\Phi \ d^3x=\epsilon_0\oint_S\delta\Phi\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial n}\ d^2S-\epsilon_0\int_V \delta\Phi\Delta\Phi\ d^3x
$$

### Question:

How $\oint_S\delta\Phi\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial n}\ d^2S$ can be written as $\nabla\Phi\ \delta\Phi\bigg|_{\partial V}$ is beyond me. It seems to me that $\nabla\Phi\ \delta\Phi\bigg|_{\partial V}$ is a vector while $\oint_S\delta\Phi\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial n}\ d^2S$ is a scalar.

Thanks

Comment: but evaluation on the boundary of a volume... what does that mean? How can we evaluate a vector on a surface? The only natural answer that comes to mind for me is surface integration. It seems to me possible this is just a cute notation for the more careful mathematics you describe. I haven't scoured Jackson for an alternative interpretation, these are just my thoughts based on your post.

Comment: Agree, that is why I find the original derivation suspicious.

Comment: Your formula is correct except it should be $\Delta \Phi$ in the last term.

Comment: Yes, you are right, Shuhao Cao, I already correct the typo, thanks.